# How to visit the elements after using `simple_load_file()` to load an xml file

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I intend to fetch some certain data from xml files. I used `simple_load_file()` to load an xml file and get the object elements, but I don't know how to visit them. The xml file is like following:

```
<?mxl version="1.0">
<metaData>
<Application version="1.0" type="32">
   <options>
       <section name="A">
           <description>...</description>
           ...
       <section name="B">
       ....
   </options>
</Application>
</metaData>
```

My code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
echo $xml->Application->version; // get the version but failed
echo $xml->Application->options->section...//I want to get the data from each section, but I don't know how to visit the elements.
```

Comment: Debug it by yourself `print_r($xml)`. [PHP Manual is great too](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

Comment: shouldn't work very well

Comment: you can try $xml->Application['version']

Comment: @Peter That's actually pretty bad advice in this case: SimpleXML is an API, not an object factory, and `print_r` will *not* tell you how to use it.

Comment: There is a manual page on [Basic SimpleXML usage](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) which should cover the kinds of operation you want. Keep in mind the difference between attributes (like `version="1.0"`) and elements (like `section`).

Comment: @IMSoP: `print_r($xml);` is an example straight from php manual :-)

Comment: @Peter Which page is that on? It should be corrected in line with this warning which appears on many of the pages: "Note: SimpleXML has made a rule of adding iterative properties to most methods. They cannot be viewed using var_dump() or anything else which can examine objects."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before i answer this question, let me tell you a little tip, whenever you have any problem try searching it on google, like in this case, i would search:

```
PHP simplexml examples
```

Ok, lets say we have a XML content:

```
<?php
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<movies>
 <movie>
  <title>PHP: Behind the Parser</title>
  <characters>
   <character>
    <name>Ms. Coder</name>
    <actor>Onlivia Actora</actor>
   </character>
   <character>
    <name>Mr. Coder</name>
    <actor>El Act&#211;r</actor>
   </character>
  </characters>
  <plot>
   So, this language. It's like, a programming language. Or is it a
   scripting language? All is revealed in this thrilling horror spoof
   of a documentary.
  </plot>
  <great-lines>
   <line>PHP solves all my web problems</line>
  </great-lines>
  <rating type="thumbs">7</rating>
  <rating type="stars">5</rating>
 </movie>
</movies>
XML;
?>
```

We can parse the XML data this way:

```
<?php


$movies = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

echo $movies->movie[0]->plot;
?>
```

For more example please visit: 
http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

For this question specific, you should use the [SimpleXMLElement::children](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php)

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
// attribute accessing
$version = (string)$xml->Application['version']
// or
$version = (string)$xml->Application->attributes()->version;


// acess children
foreach($xml->Application->section as $section)
{
    // you can work with single section here
}

// or other way
foreach($xml->Application->children() as $section)
{
    // you can work with single section here
}
```

Comment: You gave two choices, which one performs better?

Comment: @ST3 Why do you assume there is a performance difference? Unless it was a huge difference, it wouldn't matter. In this case, there really isn't any, it's just alternative syntax for doing the same thing.

Comment: I just wanted to annoy my roommate, as he wanted to be very clever.

Comment: @ST3 there shouldn't be significant performance difference, only thing between `children()` and simply `section` would be that first one would get all chidren in Application node and latter would give only section nodes